# Referring dependent jars from tomcat in spring REST application

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I have created a REST service as springbootapplication. I am deploying my war in tomcat 8.0. There are some dependent jars which my application uses. I want to keep them in tomcat container which my REST app can refer at run time. 
Please assist me how can i refer those jars.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's a maven project you will want to `scope` those dependencies as `provided`.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Comment: But where will I put my external dependencies on tomcat srever?